# Findall/3 save in list while condition not true

Tags: prolog

I am trying to use the findall/3 predicate to find all results while a condition is not true. Then I would like to cut the tree to be more efficient. 
Example here :

```
test(ListResult):-
   findall(Alpha,
      (  between(1,7,X),
         recu(X,Alpha,Beta),
         write('Alpha'),write(Alpha),write('Beta'),write(Beta),
         Alpha>Beta,
         write('cut'),
         !
      ),
      ListResult).

recu(X,Alpha,Beta):-
   random(0,5,A),
   random(0,5,Beta),
   Alpha is A+X.
```

It cut at the good time but logically save only the number when the `Alpha>Beta` condition is true.
Actual results :

```
Alpha1Beta3Alpha2Beta2Alpha3Beta1cut
ListResult = [3]
```

Wanted result :

```
Alpha1Beta3Alpha2Beta2Alpha3Beta1cut
ListResult = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Seems you do not want a cut at all. What do you actually want?

Comment: Each time I run this, I get a different result; each has been different from both your "actual" and wanted results.

Comment: I want to cut as soon as the condition is true. To avoid calculating remaining possibilites. 
I just put here an example with random numbers, to simulate the actual program

Comment: `( Alpha > Beta -> ! ; true )`

Comment: Your solution works, thank you !